# How to count Table Cells in UIAutomation IOS

Tags: xcode5, ios-ui-automation, xcode-instruments

How to calculate total number of cells through Instruments in IOS if cells are creating randomly in UITableView.

Comment: I had tried to calculate but it was not giving right count. I am writing some part of code:\n var temp = application.mainWindow().collectionView()[0].cells()[0].tableViews()[0].cells()[0]; \n var x=0;\nfor(var i in temp){x = x +1 } \n UILogger.logMessage(x);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use [`UIAElementArray.length`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Reference/UIAElementArrayClassReference/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/javascript/instp/UIAElementArray/length) property? From the code provided in comment it should look like this:

```
var cellsCount = application
                    .mainWindow()
                    .collectionView()[0]
                    .cells()[0]
                    .tableViews()[0]
                    .cells()
                    .length;

UIALogger.logMessage(cellsCount);
```